# Null pointer exception while setting image in child view of Expandable list view

Tags: android, adapter, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I am getting a `Null Pointer Exception` in the line `child.bg[i] = bground[0];`. I'm trying to set image in `ImageView` of child item. I have a `ImageView` and `TextView` in Child item layout. Here is the code of populating data in `Expandable List View`.

```
List<GroupItem> items = new ArrayList<GroupItem>();

    int[] bground ={R.drawable.hawamahal,R.drawable.tajmahal,R.drawable.mysorepalace};
    // Populate our list with groups and it's children
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        GroupItem item = new GroupItem();

        switch(i){

            case 0: item.title = "Western India";
            {
                    ChildItem child = new ChildItem();
                    child.title = getString(R.string.WestDescription);
                   child.bg[i] = bground[0];
                    item.items.add(child);
            }
                break;
            case 1: item.title = "Northern India";
            {
                ChildItem child = new ChildItem();
                child.title = getString(R.string.NorthDescription);
                child.bg[i] = bground[1];

                item.items.add(child);

            }
                break;
            case 2: item.title = "Southern India";
            {
                    ChildItem child = new ChildItem();
                    child.title = getString(R.string.SouthDescription);
                child.bg[i] = bground[2];
                    item.items.add(child);

            }

                break;


        }
        items.add(item);
    }
```

`

And the code of Adapter and Holders

```
private static class GroupItem {
    String title;
    List<ChildItem> items = new ArrayList<ChildItem>();
}

private static class ChildItem {
    String title;
    int[]  bg;

}

private static class ChildHolder {
    TextView title;
    ImageView  childimage;
}

private static class GroupHolder {
    TextView title;

}

/**
 * Adapter for our list of {@link GroupItem}s.
 */
private class ExampleAdapter extends AnimatedExpandableListView.AnimatedExpandableListAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    private List<GroupItem> items;

    public ExampleAdapter(Context context) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public void setData(List<GroupItem> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public ChildItem getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return items.get(groupPosition).items.get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getRealChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ChildHolder holder;
        int[] bg={R.drawable.taj};
        ChildItem item = getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ChildHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textTitle);
            holder.childimage= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ChildImageView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ChildHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.title.setText(item.title);
        holder.childimage.setImageResource(bg[groupPosition]);


        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRealChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return items.get(groupPosition).items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public GroupItem getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return items.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        GroupHolder holder;
        GroupItem item = getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new GroupHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_item, parent, false);
            holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textTitle);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (GroupHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.title.setText(item.title);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int arg0, int arg1) {
        return true;
    }


}
```

I am new to android development and if you need any further details do tell me. Here I am trying to set an image from drawable folder in ImageView of ChildItem. If there is any other way of doing so please tell me. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Mark the line where the exception occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You failed to initialize child.bg[] array inside ChildItem class.
Change your code as follows:

```
 ChildItem child = new ChildItem();
 child.title = getString(R.string.WestDescription);
 child.bg[] = new int[3]; // <----- initiliaze bg[] arrays
 child.bg[i] = bground[0];
 item.items.add(child);
```